# Unable to log to a file executing infinite loops while polling data from python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, logging, python-telegram-bot

I'm NOT a programmer, but a very enthusiast user :)
I've implemented a logger with influxdb, grafana and a connection to a modbus interface via tcp/ip with python. All works well, but i have a big issue, i cannot have LOGS of the activities, maybe for the bad construct i've used.
Basically i should have the bot listening, and another infinite thread who pull data from an inverter.
Here is a cutted version of the construct i've used:

```
def start(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('Whatever command/action/function i want')

def anothercommand(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('Whatever command/action/function i want')

def loop(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    print('Starting thread for automations')
    def thread1(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
        while 1:
            #loop to collect data into dB and send automated TG Alerts
            update.message.reply_text('I am from thread 1. going to sleep now.')
            time.sleep(2)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1,args=(update,context))
    t1.start()

def main() -> None:
    print('bot started..')
    updater = Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    loop(updater,CallbackContext)
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('anothercommand', anothercommand))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...forcing the logging to a file :

```
sys.stdout = open('/the/path/to/your/file', 'w')
```

or with

```
file.py > output.txt
```

or

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

generate an empty logfile, and nothing appears on the console. How i should figure out?

Answer (score 0):

From your code it does not look like you write to the log.

If you go with "import logging", you need to write to the log like this:

```
logging.warning("What you need to log") # this will be level warning in the log
logging.debug("What you need to log") # this will be level debug in the log
logging.error("What you need to log") # this will be level error in the log
... #other logging levels
```

In the basicConfig you set the lever of what logs you to see in the example.log file

You can see the log level here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

With logging:

```
import logging

    
def start(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    logging.debug("Start")
    update.message.reply_text('Whatever command/action/function i want')
    
def anothercommand(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    logging.debug("Another command")
    update.message.reply_text('Whatever command/action/function i want')

def loop(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    print('Starting thread for automations')
    logging.debug("Starting thread for automations")
    def thread1(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
        while 1:
            #loop to collect data into dB and send automated TG Alerts
            update.message.reply_text('I am from thread 1. going to sleep now.')
            time.sleep(2)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1,args=(update,context))
    t1.start()

def main() -> None:
    print('bot started..')
    logging.debug("Bot started..")
    updater = Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    loop(updater,CallbackContext)
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('anothercommand', anothercommand))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Surely i've tried a lot of codes, but i fall always in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially resolved...

obviously i had inserted before code for logging, but i have simplied the code to have your opinion.
Now i'm logging into a file (and see also logs on the console), but it don't catch all exeptions...

With a function (like "anothercommand"), who calls a second one (gpio setup for automation), i have an error logged to the console, but NOT in the file (related to an OUT assignment on an already assigned gpio pin).

Here is the code i'm running, outside the **main** def:

```
# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
```